# how can i get a div on my page from another web server with jquery or any javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webserver

I want to add a specific div from another web server to my webpage. How can I do that with jquery ore any other javascript code?

I'm a really beginer on javascript and a bit more explanations can be helpful.

Comment: In general, it's not possible to do this with client-side JS code only, I'm afraid; otherwise our shaky world would be even less secure. You have to fetch the external page with your server-side scripts, fetch that interesting DIV from it, then serve it as your own.

Comment: can i do it with php to do that and how can i do it with php ?

Comment: how can I break that sameorigine policy

Comment: You should run your own local web server, and it is the server side (PHP) that fetches the remote page (in PHP you can use cUrl to do that). Another possibility to avoid XHR Same Origin Policy is to disable web security in your browser. For instance in Chrome: $ google-chrome --disable-web-security

Comment: Yes, you can: use curl extension or http stream wrapper + file_get_contents combo to fetch the file from external source, then either serve it as whole (and process the response with JS) or extract the required element (with DOMDocument or any other similar tool) and serve just it. ) Both ways effectively make your 'parent' client side script affect content from the same domain.

Comment: check out jquery get http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/